# Keydown functionality in a input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to key down my search results and for this i am using this jquery below:

```
$('#ChangeAccountInput').keydown(function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode==40)
    {
        $('#results').css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
});
```

But the problem is, it is applying to the full div not on a single value.

[image: <code>Picture</code>]

Above jquery applying to all like:

[image: <code>Picture2</code>]

**html:**

```
<input  id='ChangeAccountInput' class="InputBorder" placeholder="Search" style="display: none; margin-top: -79px; margin-left: -226px; border: 1px solid rgb(133, 133, 133); font-family: calibri; font-size: 15px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 21px; width: 182px"/>
<i class="icon-search" id="iconsearch1" style="display: none; margin-top: -37px; margin-left: -22px;"></i>


<div id="results" stlye='display: none'></div>
```

**php:**

```
while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "<a href='#'>";
    echo '<font>'.$row['ACCOUNT_TYPE'].'</font>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo "<div style='border: 1px solid #AAAAAA; margin-left: -4px'></div>";
    echo "</a>";
}
```

**ajax:**

```
$.ajax
({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Reports/Account Search.php',
    data: 'GetAccountInput='+GetAccountInput,
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('#results').html(data);
        $('#results').show();
    }
});
```

**Account Search File:**

```
<?php

  error_reporting(0);

  $user = "fyp";
  $pass = "fyp";
  $host = "localhost/CRMP";

  // Connection with the Oracle.
  $con = oci_connect($user, $pass, $host);

  // If connection is established with the Oracle or not. 
  if (!$con)
  {
      //header('location:../../../Extra/Error_Other.php');
  }

  else
  {
      //echo "Connected to Oracle.";
  }
?>

<?php

    $GetAccount = $_GET['GetAccountInput'];

    if($GetAccount != '')
    {
        $query = oci_parse($con, "SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT_TYPE FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ACCOUNT_TYPE LIKE '%".$GetAccount."%'");
        oci_execute($query);

        $check = oci_fetch_array($query);
        if(empty($check))
        {
            echo "<a href='#'>";
            echo "No Result Found";
            echo "</a>";
        }

        while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            echo "<a>";
            echo $row['ACCOUNT_TYPE'];
            echo '<br>';
            echo "</a>";
            echo "<div style='border: 1px solid #777A79; margin-left: -6px'></div>";
        }
    }

    else
    {

    }
?>
```

[image: <code>Sample</code>]

Help would be apprciated.

Comment: Any chance you can post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS please.

Comment: It looks like you're applying the same id to each 'results'. ID's must be unique!

Comment: @kehrk updated above.

Comment: @mister_rampage yes but it will take some time.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard generating this using php code. don't know how to.

Comment: @JayBlanchard `#results` may be the wrapper, it is unclear without the markup

Comment: I'm trying to setup a fiddle for this and I can see that we're missing a lot of markup and other information. Please setup a fiddle that demonstrates the problem, including all of the relevant markup and then we'll be able to help.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard i will try but tell me how i gonna make a list in js fiddle? i am getting the list from database as u can see above.

Comment: Just make one up for now, enough to properly test. You can apply the same markup as the stuff comes from the database.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard here http://jsfiddle.net/2wk6Q/1084/ sorry for the wait. the values coming from the php part are in a tags.

Comment: so you want this to highlight the first answer it finds with that keycode?

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard ops this one is right  http://jsfiddle.net/2wk6Q/1086/

Comment: WAIT - your description of what you want is WAY, WAY off! You want to do a drop-down and color each subsequent item when the key is pressed.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard yes and then after selecting first it moves down to second as key presses.

Comment: Are you using autocomplete? If so, you need to rewrite your question.

Comment: yes i want like a dropdown where you can move up and down with using keys

Comment: Jay Blanchard no i am not using autocomplete.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard i want to make it like a google.--> Suggestion shows when we are typing and we can select the suggestions using arrow keys. did you got it now?

Comment: I took a quick stab when I had a couple of minutes but I need to go back and work out iterating through each element. Even at that it should give you and idea of what you're looking to do. http://jsfiddle.net/2wk6Q/1090/

Comment: @Jay Blanchard thankyou so much that was what i wanted. please post your answer so i can accept.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard why its stoping at 2nd link?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard has one other problem. when you pressdown key button. scrollbar also moves down. i tried e.Preventdefault but that didn't work.

Comment: It stops at the second one because I wasn't really finished. This was just something I threw together quickly. As soon as I have something working I'll post, I just wanted to give you an idea of what was involved.

Comment: Jay Blanchard okay thanks so much.

Comment: I posted something I think you can work with.

Comment: Let me know if this will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about this some more and I came up with a solution that will work for you. All you should have to do is add the kind of styling that you want and other animations as needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/2wk6Q/1095/

```
$('#ChangeAccountInput').keydown(function (e) { //not actually the down key though :-)
    if ($('a').hasClass('yellowBack')) { // do any links have this class?
        var selected = $('a.yellowBack'); // if the do, they are the 'selected' link
        selected.removeClass('yellowBack'); // this cleans up the one that we move from

        if (40 == e.keyCode) { // going down the list
            if (selected.next().length == 0) {
                // if there isn't another list item, highlight the first
                $('#results a:first').addClass('yellowBack');
            } else {
                // add the class to the next item                                
                selected.next().addClass('yellowBack');
            }
        } else { // going up the list
            if (selected.prev().length == 0) {
                // add the class to the last item if you have gone to the top of the list
                $("#results a:last").addClass("yellowBack");
            } else {
                // add the class to the next one up the list
                selected.prev().addClass('yellowBack');
            }
        }
    } else {
        // if none were initially selected, select the first one
        $("#results a:first").addClass("yellowBack");
    }
});
```

This will allow you to move up and down the returned list, no matter what length the list is. Proper styling will prevent scrollbar issues that you mentioned above.

EDIT: modifying PHP so that output matches latest fiddle -

```
while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "<div style='border-bottom: 2px solid #777A79; margin-left: -4px'>";
    echo "<a href='#'>";
    echo '<font>'.$row['ACCOUNT_TYPE'].'</font>';
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

The reason for the modification is because the PHP is essentially outputting HTML that is hard to work with in JavaScript. The OP is learning how to format ALL of his code, from back to front, so that it plays nicely together.

Comment: `$('a.yellowBack');` is working for the first a item only. my <a> tags comes from the other php file using ajax. in that case the above `selected.next().addClass('yellowBack');` is not working. This code is working pretty fine if i add <a> tags by myself like you did in the jsfiddle instead of getting <a> tags from the php file. any help sir?

Comment: I'd need to see the format of the HTML that you're getting from the PHP file. Can you copy and paste that in your original post? My bet is that the next() and prev() functions may not work as we desire, but if I can see the actual markup I can fix it.

Comment: I need the actual HTML output from that PHP file. Can you post that?

Comment: from using inspect element?

Comment: Either that, or view source.

Comment: Yikes! Can you actually copy and paste the markup? I don't want to have to retype it all into the fiddle.

Comment: OK - let me see what I can do

Comment: Wow, that HTML is really badly formed. Is there anyone who can change it for you?

Comment: I will update the fiddle with the new format and then provide you with changes for your PHP.

Comment: The PHP is now in my post.

Comment: oho sorry i mistakenly posted that `continue this discussion in chat`